# Can Wordpress search an external website?

Tags: wordpress, search

Can the standard Wordpress search or one of the search plugins index another (external to Wordpress) website?

Answer (score 0):

Not inherently, you could create a search engine, or easier would be to embed a [Google custom search](https://www.google.com/cse).

I haven't used this plugin, so cannot say if it works or is any good - but this might be a place to start. [Google Custom Search Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/google-custom-search/)